# RecurrencePattern: range of recurrence - "End after X" vs "End by date"?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I have a VSTO Outlook Add-in and I need to collect all calendar and tasks items with all their properties. This is ok, but the problem come when I use the RecurrencePattern. It works very well and returns almost all properties that I need, except one.

In the 'Range of recurrence' form the user can choose how long to continue his task when he choose on of the tree radio buttons.

- No end date
- End after: 3(for example) occurrences
- End by: some date

The RecurrencePattern have a boolean property only for the first one - No end date.

When the first radio is not marked I need to understand which one of the second or third is marked, but RecurrencePattern does not have a property for them. It returns the number of occurrences and end date, but I need the checked radio button.

I am wondering can I have a event on these radio buttons or can I take their boolean properties in some other way, but I can't find anything about that.

I don't use Ribbon or some other form and I don't need to use it in this case.

My Outlook is 2016 and the .net framework is 4.6.1.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For some inexplicable reason, Outlook Object Model does not expose that information. You can either parse the recurrence pattern blob yourself (its format is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203303(v=exchg.80).aspx), but isn't fun to parse) or you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDORecurrencePattern](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDORecurrencePattern.htm).`PatternEndKind` property. Assuming a recurring appointment is selected in Outlook:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set appt = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
  strPattern = "Not recurring"
  if appt.IsRecurring Then
    set pattern = appt.GetRecurrencePattern
    select case pattern.PatternEndKind
      case 0 strPattern = "No end date"  'rekNoEndDate
      case 1 strPattern = "End after X occurrences"  'rekEndAfterOccurrences
      case 2 strPattern = "End by date"  'rekEndByDate
    end select
  End If
  MsgBox strPattern
```

Answer (score 0):

1. See [NoEndDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/recurrencepattern-noenddate-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm281)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).
2. Looks like you are interested in the [Occurrences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/recurrencepattern-occurrences-property-outlook) property of the `RecurrencePattern` class which returns a Long indicating the number of occurrences of the recurrence pattern. This property allows the definition of a recurrence pattern that is only valid for the specified number of subsequent occurrences. For example, you can set this property to 10 for a formal training course that will be held on the next ten Thursday evenings. This property must be coordinated with other properties when setting up a recurrence pattern. If the `PatternEndDate` property or the `Occurrences` property is set, the pattern is considered to be finite and the `NoEndDate` property is False . If neither `PatternEndDate` nor `Occurrences` is set, the pattern is considered infinite and `NoEndDate` is True.
3. The [PatternEndDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/recurrencepattern-patternenddate-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm283)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property of the `RecurrencePattern` class returns a Date indicating the end date for the recurrence pattern. This property is optional but must be coordinated with other properties when setting up a recurrence pattern. If this property or the Occurrences property is set, the pattern is considered to be finite, and the `NoEndDate` property is False . If neither `PatternEndDate` nor Occurrences is set, the pattern is considered infinite and `NoEndDate` is True . The Interval property must be set before setting `PatternEndDate` .

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to set the properties. I need to get them. I know how to set them, but they didn't have a property that returns boolean for radio buttons. Only NoEndDate has.

Comment: Have you tried using properties mentioned in my answer? The `Occurences` property corresponds to the second option from the dialog. And the `PatternEndDate` property allows to check the third option. But before using these properties you need to the check the `NoEndDate` property which corresponds to the first option.

Comment: These two properties did not return boolean values. They return int for Occurences and DateTime for PatternEndDate. In this way you can't understand which one of them is checked.

Comment: Try to play with a dialog and check their values. If `NoEndDate` is false and `PatternEndDate` is not set (or set to a default value) then the second option is chosen.

Comment: It does not have a default value. It is always set and it is calculated automatically when second option is set